# Как можно защитится от SQL-инъекции через UNION

Tags: php, mysql

Привет.Какой способ самый лучший?Фильтровать строку на слово UNION?
Можно ли на сервере отключить эту операцию?

Также способом инъекции является использование коментария  -- .Как можно обезопасить при таком случае свой запрос (mysql_real_escape поможет?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее надежным способом предотвращения SQL-инъекций является использование параметризированных SQL-параметров. В случае с PHP это возможно с помощью пакета PEAR’s DB, предлагающего интерфейс для выполнения абсолютно безопасных SQL-выражений. Обращение к БД происходит следующим образом: $p = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?"); $db->execute($p, array($_GET['id'])).

Comment: PDO решает эти проблемы значит.А в mysql без него как поступали раньше?

Comment: @zloctb - так и поступали - были дырявыми.